# Make a call to server always running in background

Tags: android

I want my app to make a call to server always in background checking for any updates , I am new to android and not sure how to perform this to start with. I just want a single call always running in background. Please guide me with this to start with.

Comment: try IntentService or Service
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: You can try [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) if you want to check for update once like when starts your app etc. other wise comment of @jenil is good.

Comment: I want to check updated even if app is not started

Comment: @Napolean   Can we keep service always running in background even when app is closed?

Comment: yes you can have it done by using Service class which once started using startService(Intent ) keeps on running indefinitely until unless stopped by using stopService(Intent) or stopSelf()  or killed by Android system under memory pressure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Async Task` for that. In your `doInBackground()` method, call your service providing some timespan.

Snippet to add timestamp:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
    new AddStringTask().execute();
} }, 0, 5000);
```

Comment: Does this makes a call to server to run for years ? my use case is like has in whatsapp even though we are not online it pops up messages by running in background

Comment: Web services run even for years. In your case, use notifications which are the result of Your service call

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293925/push-notification-on-android-with-webservices) this may help you

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GuzC1ZFk ,i am already calling webservice like this,so u mean to say this already running in background?

Comment: that is eventhough i have come out of my app,this call is made again n again?

Comment: Yes,if you have used asynctask then it is in background. But to run it say for every 5 sec,give the webservice call after every 5 seconds.

Comment: any snippet for this ? for setting timer

Comment: and once it runs in background how will i get notification of updation on device main screen ,like whatsapp?

Comment: [This link may help you to give timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207362/how-to-run-an-async-task-for-every-x-mins-in-android)

Comment: pastebin.com/GuzC1ZFk   please see this,i need to add timer only on invokeGetReminderWS,how to do this ?please edit in my code

Comment: I guess this AsyncTask wont work when app is closed we need to use Service

Comment: jaude yar, bore zal ata mazch mla yet nahiye,tuz kuthun karu,itk pan nahi yet mla Android...

Comment: Yes,sorry i meant to say that u must use background services for that purpose