# How server can send event to app

Tags: android, rest, android-intent

I do not know much about REST servers notifications, so how can I get server's notification\event on my Android app? One way I can suppose is send request to server and wait until response which is delayed, but this decision seems me wrong. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: that also depends on what the server supports, does it support push notifications or are you able to only poll it

Comment: @Zhuinden I have small free test ASP.NET server on http://myasp.net

Comment: have you tried looking into https://docs.pushbullet.com/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261718/gcm-push-notification-with-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the documentation in Android developers.

One way to do what you want is called Push Notifications and is doing throw Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).

It involves using Google APIs, to code some classes in your Android App, and to code other stuff in your server part.

By the end, you should be able to send a simple message to a device and show a notification.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html