# GCM request in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, google-cloud-messaging

I have reffered this link for sending GCM request and it is working perfectly fine. [gcm-push-notification-with-asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11651066/3409734)

I referred one more link to post `JSON` [how-to-post-json-to-the-server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16380064/3409734)

On the basis of second link I have tried the following code.

```
        var httprequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        httprequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httprequest.Method = "POST";
        httprequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GCM.APIKey));
        httprequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", GCM.ProjectNo));

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httprequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new GCMValues
            {
                delay_while_idle = false,
                priority = "high",
                registration_id = regId,
                data = new MessagesValues
                {
                    message = message
                }
            });

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httprequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Properties that I have used

```
public class GCMValues
{
    public Object data { get; set; }
    public bool delay_while_idle { get; set; }
    public String priority { get; set; }
    public String registration_id { get; set; }
}
public class MessagesValues
{
    public String message { get; set; }
    public DateTime? time { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I am facing is at line `var httpResponse =(HttpWebResponse)httprequest.GetResponse();`

I am getting a response of bad request.
Where I went wrong or what could be done to pass the values in `JSON` format for `GCM` post request.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `registration_ids` (plural) not `registration_id` (singular) in the JSON. It is an array of strings , not a single string value.

If you check the [GCM documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) it gives all the JSON options.

Elsewhere the documentation details how to use `to` if you have just one token to send a notification to, as in this example:

```
  {
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks I have used the hints provided by you, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following way to get it done, and it worked.

```
var httprequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        httprequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httprequest.Method = "POST";
        httprequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GCM.APIKey));
        httprequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", GCM.ProjectNo));
        String[] regid = regId.Split(',');

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httprequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new GCMValues
            {
                delay_while_idle = false,
                priority = "high",
                registration_ids = regid,
                data = new MessagesValues
                {
                    message = message
                }
            });

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httprequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            if (result.Contains("Error"))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Properties that I have used

```
public class GCMValues
{
    public Object data { get; set; }
    public bool delay_while_idle { get; set; }
    public String priority { get; set; }
    public String[] registration_ids { get; set; }
}
public class MessagesValues
{
    public String message { get; set; }
    public DateTime? time { get; set; }
}
```